# Android Java NumberFormatException: Invalid Double on Tip Calculator

Tags: java, android, double

am working on a basic tip calculator and running into the following program crash. The log for the crash is:

```
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText@41634f08"
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:114)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at mkelleyjr.example.tippycalc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3540)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14167)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4558)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-24 01:03:43.602: E/AndroidRuntime(27213):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_main.xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:text="Total Bill Amount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/res"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="Result : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/res"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="Enter Tip % :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bill_amt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bill_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java is:

```
package mkelleyjr.example.tippycalc;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText amt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_amt);
    final EditText tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_percent);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

    Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString());
                    double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.toString());
                    double tip_cal = (amount * tip_per) / 100;
                    result.setText("Result : " + Double.toString(tip_cal));

                }
            });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Not sure exactly why it's crashing saying invalid double at the moment. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException:
 Invalid double:"android.widget.EditText@41634f08"
```

You are passing `editText` `Object`'s reference as `String` in `parseDouble(String)` Method in `Double.parseDouble(amt.toString())` and `Double.parseDouble(tip.toString());` instead use

```
Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString())
```

**or**

```
Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString())
```

in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString()); 
 double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.toString());
```

is wrong

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.getText().toString());    
 double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.getText().toString());
```

The correct way

And also add

in EditText  xml

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the text from `EditText` in a wrong way. By calling `amt.toString()` you just get default `Java` string representation of the class. The proper way is:

```
EditText.getText().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.toString());
```

Here `amt.toString()` will return the string representation of `amt EditText`. We need the text entered in amt TextView so use following:

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.getText().toString());
```